# How to extend an assigned namespace

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, c++14, c++17

I want to explain my question over an instance. I am using an third party library, having its own namespace. I want to import a part of this library, having its own namespace inside the namespace mentioned below.

```
namespace library {
  namespace part {
  }
}
```

There is also a hierarchy in the current project. I want to import and extend the **library::part** inside to my project with another name. I try to do as below:

```
#include <library/part>

namespace project {
  namespace my_part = library::part;
}

namespace project {
  namespace my_part {
    void my_extension_1();
    void my_extension_2();
  }
}
```

The scenario can be done with the current tools of the language? If not, how should a workaround can be done? Still not, why?

**Edit:** Error message gcc 5.3.0 dumps:

> error: conflicting declaration of namespace ‘project::my_part’

**Edit:** There is a suggestion about extending the original namespace, but that I am asking for. **library::part** users should not have a direct access to the functions I have added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you want to make a namespace of your own that contains
everything that `library::part` contains, and more besides, without
putting anything more into `library::part`. Like this?

```
namespace library {
    namespace part {
        const int library_part_i = 123;
    }
}

namespace project {
    namespace part {
        using namespace library::part;
        void my_extension_1(){};
        void my_extension_2(){};
    }
}

int main()
{
    // const int i = library_part_i;    <- Does not compile
    // const int i = project::library_part_i; <- Does not compile
    const int i = project::part::library_part_i;
    // library::part::my_extension_1();  <- Does not compile
    project::part::my_extension_2();
    return 0;
}
```